# Can anyone help me on the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This site can’t be reached 35.238.10.203 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Works fine for me on port 80.  Can you add detail as to exactly what the problem is?  What are you trying to connect to?  What is at that address?  The message connection refused is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Works fine for me on port 80

Comment: Hi, trying to access my cloud server:http://35.238.10.203:8080/holiztech/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your service in not listening on port 8080, if you run an nmap to check the status of that port:

nmap 35.238.10.203 -Pn -p 8080

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-22 20:48 EDT
Host is up (0.041s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE

8080/tcp closed http-proxy

Running cURL also you get:

curl -I 35.238.10.203:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.238.10.203 port 8080: Connection refused

You'd need to assure that the port is open and the service is listening and responding a HTTP 200 (OK) to the requests.

Additionally, could you please check if there is a configured [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) allowing connections to port 8080 and also that there is none denying it.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I am not a IT person however I will attemp to see if I can see any of the issues you kindly mentioned. I have access to the google platform and will review these menu items. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall rules or whitelist your local ip on firewall